# Installed SSL certificate has no effect

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate, https

I have installed a free Comodo SSL certificate to shared hosting for my domain. Totally 5 .crt files. However they have no effect. I cannot open my https://example.com domain.

Comment: More detail needed. What happens exactly when you try to open your site?

Comment: When I type https: //example .com Firefox says "Unable to connect, Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at example.com, etc."

Comment: The HTTPS port (port 443) is closed. You need to tell Apache to listen on the HTTPS port.

Comment: Also note cert.gov issued a warning regarding [Comodo issuing fraudulent SSL certificates](http://www.us-cert.gov/current/index.html#fradulent_ssl_certificates) for some very high profile domains today (login.live.com, mail.google.com), which is a very serious mistake. [Many browsers issued updates to block these certificates](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/security/microsoft-warns-fraudulent-digital-certificates-issued-for-high-value-websites/8488). I wonder if these updates are blocking some other Certificates from Comodo SSL as well.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it concerns the use of shared web hosting by end users or resellers, rather than the administration of web hosting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set apache to listen on port 443 (in ports.conf or httpd.conf), you need at least create a virtualserver for port 443 and a config file pointing to the certificate. Tell us if you did that and what error do you have so we can try to help you solving your problem better.

Comment: Sounds like he's using CPannel, and depending on how it's configured, all of these directions might be wrong for his host...

Comment: @Chris S - You're right. I just wanted to give him a start on where to look if he was lost but it is true this is only valid for "normal" apache config.